# $_SERVER['argv'] with HTTP GET and CLI issue

Tags: php, get, query-string, command-line-interface

I'm trying to write down a script to fetch some online data; script should be invoked either by a **cron job or php cli** and with standard **GET HTTP request**. As stated on PHP website `$_SERVER['argv']` should fit my needs:

> Array of arguments passed to the script. When the script is run on the
>   command line, this gives C-style access to the command line
>   parameters. When called via the GET method, this will contain the
>   query string.

However i can't get it to work with standard HTTP GET request. `$_SERVER['argv']` is not setted. What i'm missing?

```
<?php
    // jobs/fetch.php
    var_dump($_SERVER['argv']);
?>
```

**CLI output** `php jobs/fetch.php -a -bhello`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "jobs/fetch.php"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "-a"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "-bhello"
}
```

**GET output** `jobs/fetch.php?a=&b=hello`:

> Notice: Undefined index: argv in jobs/fetch.php.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The manual didn't state this very well, but, if you want `$_SERVER['argc']`, `$_SERVER['argv']`, `$argc`, `$argv` to be registered when you are not running in `CLI` mode, then the `php.ini` value [register_argc_argv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv) needs to be enabled in php.ini (off by default [for performance reasons]).

You could do the following to get `argv`, or query string args depending on how the script is running:

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    $args = $_SERVER['argv'];
} else {
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $args);
}
```

Here are some details from `php.ini`:

```
; This directive determines whether PHP registers $argv & $argc each time it
; runs. $argv contains an array of all the arguments passed to PHP when a script
; is invoked. $argc contains an integer representing the number of arguments
; that were passed when the script was invoked. These arrays are extremely
; useful when running scripts from the command line. When this directive is
; enabled, registering these variables consumes CPU cycles and memory each time
; a script is executed. For performance reasons, this feature should be disabled
; on production servers.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to On for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/register-argc-argv
```

See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php and [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str).

Answer (score 5):

You will have to use `$_GET` *or* `$_SERVER['argv']` depending on how your script is called. Neither one is used for both.

For example:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['argv'][0]) {
  $a = $_SERVER['argv'][1];
  $b = $_SERVER['argv'][2];
} else {
  $a = $_GET['a'];
  $b = $_GET['b'];
}
```