# Get javascript values from result of php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have pie chart webpage (index.html) which is currently getting values from a static .js file.

The original content of the .js file for the pie chart is this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var ctx110 = document.getElementById("chart110").getContext("2d");

    var data110 = [ 
        {   
                "value": 40, 
                "color": "#F25656",
                "highlight": "#FD7A7A",
                "label": "Critical"
        },  
        {   
                "value": 63.2452,
                "color": "#22BAA0",
                "highlight": "#36E7C8",
                "label": "Other"
        },  
        {   
                "value": 0,
                "color": "#F2CA4C",
                "highlight": "#FBDB6E",
                "label": "Warning"
        }   
    ];  
    
    var chart110 = new Chart(ctx110).Pie(data110,{
        segmentShowStroke : true,
        segmentStrokeColor : "#fff",
        segmentStrokeWidth : 2,
        animationSteps : 100,
        animationEasing : "easeOutBounce",
        animateRotate : true,
        animateScale : false,
        legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
        responsive: true
    }); 
    
    
});
```

However, I need to make the values in the `var data110` variable dynamic.

I have a php script that, when run, spits out the required value and my issue is, I'm having problems getting the pie chart to load after I incorporate the php script into the above code.

Here's my attempt (I'm completely new to web development, so please forgive my ineptitude here - i know it's very ugly):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var ctx110 = document.getElementById("chart110").getContext("2d");
    
    function internal_loadXMLDoc1() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                        document.getElementById("myDivAX1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","getnum.php?os-metrics",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    var dskmetric = internal_loadXMLDoc1();

    var data110 = [ 
        {   
                "value": dskmetric, 
                "color": "#F25656",
                "highlight": "#FD7A7A",
                "label": "Critical"
        },  
        {   
                "value": 63.2452,
                "color": "#22BAA0",
                "highlight": "#36E7C8",
                "label": "Other"
        },  
        {   
                "value": 0,
                "color": "#F2CA4C",
                "highlight": "#FBDB6E",
                "label": "Warning"
        }   
    ];  
    
    var chart110 = new Chart(ctx110).Pie(data110,{
        segmentShowStroke : true,
        segmentStrokeColor : "#fff",
        segmentStrokeWidth : 2,
        animationSteps : 100,
        animationEasing : "easeOutBounce",
        animateRotate : true,
        animateScale : false,
        legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
        responsive: true
    }); 
    
    
});
```

EDIT (based on @AL-zami advice):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    var ctx110 = document.getElementById("chart110").getContext("2d");
    
    function internal_loadXMLDoc1() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    
                     // Do your work here
                            var data110 = [ 
                                {
                                        **"value": [this needs to be dynamic]**, 
                                        "color": "#F25656",
                                        "highlight": "#FD7A7A",
                                        "label": "Critical"
                                },
                                {
                                        **"value": [this needs to be dynamic]**,
                                        "color": "#22BAA0",
                                        "highlight": "#36E7C8",
                                        "label": "Other"
                                },
                                {
                                        "value": 0,
                                        "color": "#F2CA4C",
                                        "highlight": "#FBDB6E",
                                        "label": "Warning"
                                }
                            ];
    
                            var chart110 = new Chart(ctx110).Pie(data110,{
                                segmentShowStroke : true,
                                segmentStrokeColor : "#fff",
                                segmentStrokeWidth : 2,
                                animationSteps : 100,
                                animationEasing : "easeOutBounce",
                                animateRotate : true,
                                animateScale : false,
                                legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
                                responsive: true
                            });

                }   
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","getnum.php?os-metrics",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }   

    internal_loadXMLDoc1();


});
```

Here's the PHP script `getnum.php`:

```
<?php
$allargs = $_SERVER["argv"];
$argscou = $_SERVER["argc"];
if ( $argscou == 0 ) {
    die();
} else {
    $upatterns = var_export($allargs, true) ;
    if (strpos($upatterns, '__') !== false) {
        $type_val = explode("__", $allargs[0]);
    } else {
        $type_val = $allargs;
    }
    $compon1 = $type_val[0];
    if ($compon1== "30day-expirations") {
        $compon2 = $type_val[1];
        echo '<p class="counter">' . "$compon2" . '</p>'. "\n";
    } else if ( ($compon1 == "getnum.php") || ($compon1 == "os-disk-usage") ) {
        $duvalue = "400";
        echo "$duvalue";
        file_put_contents('4filename.txt', $duvalue, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked for error messages in [the console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)?

Comment: still stuck on this.  been at this for hours. cant seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem statement is not clear. Hard to determine what you are trying to accomplish. If I understand you correctly, your problem lies in you post request handler. XMLHttpRequest is a asynchronous request. Your rest of the code run to completion before the post request is resolved.

```
var dskmetric = internal_loadXMLDoc1();
```

The above statement doesn't return anything.  Try to run you chart generation code inside the handler function.

```
    var ctx110 = document.getElementById("chart110").getContext("2d");
    
    function internal_loadXMLDoc1() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                        
                     // Do your work here

                }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","getnum.php?os-metrics",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    internal_loadXMLDoc1();
```

If you are not submitting any form try to change the request method to `GET`

Comment: Thank you for this.  What I want to do is to be able to change the `values` in `data110` with the result of the php script.   I'm going to edit my original post to reflect the changes I just made based on your advice.  My problem is, I dont know how to replace the static values with the result of the php script.

Comment: Good to know that you have made changes. Did it worked? If not, in that case you must provide 3 things, a sample php script, desired output sample and your js code. Otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: I have added the php script to my original post.  Please review.  When I refresh my index.html page, I do see the file `4filename.txt` being updated with the `400` number.  So I know the php script working and running.

Comment: I was only able to get 400 outpur from your php code. There are some concerns in your php code. argv and argc are designed to get command line arguments. Why you are using it with javascript. XMLHttpRequests are desined to send get/post/put queries. Also argv is an array. strpos won't work with an array. use $_POST or $_GET to get data from your xmlhttprequest

Comment: have you enabled register_argc_argv in php.ini file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270030/serverargv-with-http-get-and-cli-issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example:

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        "value"     => 'dskmetric',
        "color"     => "#F25656",
        "highlight" => "#FD7A7A",
        "label"     => "Critical"
    ],
    [
        "value"     => 63.2452,
        "color"     => "#22BAA0",
        "highlight" => "#36E7C8",
        "label"     => "Other"
    ],
    [
        "value"     => 0,
        "color"     => "#F2CA4C",
        "highlight" => "#FBDB6E",
        "label"     => "Warning"
    ]
];
?>
<script type="application/json" id="j-data">
{ "data": <?php echo json_encode($data ?? []); ?>}
</script>
<script>
var data = JSON.parse($("#j-data")[0].innerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: I dont know how to implement this. I dont see where my php script is being called to produce the numbers that will replace the ones set for `"value"`.